# FB.api - are users unique?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

So in my app, I do this:

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  alert(response.name);
});
```

This gives me the users name IF they are logged into FB through my site. Now, is there a way I can get a unique ID for them as well? That way everytime they post something on my site, I can store their post along with their FB name AND Id, and then I know which posts they have made in the past when they are connected to their FB through my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `response.id` to get the Facebook Users unique id.

Comment: nop it is not, i have a case where i ask a facebook token on an android app using facebook login and this give me this id (1021117312194732?) and my personnal informations were correct when i get them.
And when i used a token from facebook explorer engine he gave me this id for me (1020782440735155?) and i still can get my informations using this id.
So i have two ids for one user...